# Filtering rows which only relate to a most recent order (Google Analytics data)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working on a BigQuery query for an attribution project and I would like to return results which show me all the sessions relating to a customers most recent orders, excluding any previous orders and sessions which led up to them.

Here is my current SQL:

```sql
select
*,
row_number() over (partition by userid order by visitstarttime asc) as row_num
from
(select 
IF(cd.index = 2, cd.value, NULL) AS userId,
concat(fullvisitorid, cast(visitid as string)) as sessionid,
visitstarttime,
hits.transaction.transactionid as transactionid
FROM
    `my_project.dataset.ga_sessions_20*`,
    UNNEST(customDimensions) AS cd,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
      parse_DATE('%y%m%d',
        _table_suffix) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
      AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
      AND cd.index = 2
  AND cd.value NOT LIKE "true"
  AND cd.value NOT LIKE "false"
  AND cd.value NOT LIKE "undefined"
  AND cd.value IS NOT NULL
  group by 1,2,3,4)
```

This code is returning all sessions with associated orders, but I only want to see those related to the most recent order. For example, here **I only want to see from row 11**:
[image]

And here **I only want to see from row 3 to row 16**:
[image]

How could I adjust my code to flag these rows accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the number of transactions *in reverse order* and take the rows where the count is `1`:

```
with q as (
      your query here
     )
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             count(transactionid) over (partition by userid order by visitstarttime desc) as grp
      from q
     ) q
 where grp = 1;
```